# Only want report to load last 30 min of data

Tags: sql, oracle, report, oracle-apex

I am trying to have an APEX report show only responses submitted in the last 30 minutes. Is it possible to do this with the where clause?

I originally tried using a trigger that feed into a creation date column but I had issues with data showing up into the column and was unable to have the report only show the past 30 minutes.

Any ideas would be helpful,

Thanks!

```
    select SCRAP_DATE,
           PAINT_SHOP,
           IGEF,
           GIRDER,
           MODEL,
           COLOR,
           SCRAP_OWNER,
           sysdate
    from SCRAP_BODY_SYSTEM
    where sysdate >= (current_timestamp - interval '30' minute)
```

Answer (score 2):

`where` clause *is* the way to do it, e.g.

```
where date_column >= sysdate - interval '30' minute
```

because of this:

```
SQL> select sysdate,
  2         sysdate - interval '30' minute half_an_hour_ago
  3  from dual;

SYSDATE          HALF_AN_HOUR_AGO
---------------- ----------------
04.05.2022 14:37 04.05.2022 14:07

SQL>
```

---

`sysdate` vs. `current_timestamp`:

```
SQL> select sysdate, current_timestamp from dual;

SYSDATE             CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
------------------- -------------------------------
05.05.2022 07:48:19 05.05.22 07:48:19,200858 +02:00

SQL>
```

Comment: I am confused, is sysdate a built in function in APEX?

Comment: It is an Oracle built-in function.

Comment: Does the new added code make sense? It took me a bit to get sysdate working, and I think it assigned the same sysdate and time for all of my data that has already been entered so everything shows up at the moment. Just want to make sure is makes sense

Comment: No, it doesn't make any sense. SYSDATE and CURRENT_TIMESTAMP are both built-in functions (SYSDATE returns database server date and time; CURRENT_TIMESTAMP returns current date and time in session time zone; *usually* they are just the same - see example I posted in edited answer). You should compare SYSDATE or CURRENT_TIMESTAMP to a **column in the table**. Code you use now compares SYSDATE to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, and that's pointless.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72143409/apex-report-to-load-last-30-min-of-data

Comment: plz reference above link

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could use a where condition which would be something like:

```
where submitted_datetime >= (current_timestamp - interval '30' minute)
```

Do let me know if it works!

Comment: Im assuming to do this I would need to create a submitted_datetime column in my table?

Comment: Nope, just the datetime column which has the response submitted date and time.

Comment: Instead of referring to "submitted_datetime", you can call the name of the column of interest @bbowen14

Comment: I think I am lost on what the datetime column is. I do not currently have one, so I was assuming I'd need to make one

Comment: What are the columns you have in the table?

Comment: I don't currently have this column, I have tried doing this but have ad issues with it actually storing the submission date and time in the table. is there a better way to do so?

Comment: Without the submission date and time column, you will have no reference to add the condition for finding the responses in the last 30 mins

Comment: I have this column now and used the same exact code you posted. Recieveing this issue:

Comment: ORA-20999: Failed to parse SQL query! ORA-06550: line 3, column 50: ORA-00936: missing expression

Comment: You may need to post the complete query in order to be able to debug.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72143409/apex-report-to-load-last-30-min-of-data

Comment: Reference their for a new attempt I made