# Apex Report to load last 30 min of data

Tags: sql, oracle-apex, apex

I am trying to have an APEX report show only responses submitted in the last 30 minutes. Is it possible to do this with the where clause? Getting stuck with all of this errors shown below:
[image]

Here is my current code:

```
    select SCRAP_DATE,
           PAINT_SHOP,
           MODEL,
           COLOR,
           SCRAP_OWNER,
           DEPARTMENT_CODE,
           REASON_FOR_SCRAP,
           SCRAP_TYPE,
           BODY_TYPE,
           DETAILS,
           COMMENTS,
           SUBMITTED_DATETIME
    from SCRAP_BODY_SYSTEM

    SQL> select sysdate,
   2         sysdate - interval '30' minute half_an_hour_ago
   3  from dual;

   SYSDATE          HALF_AN_HOUR_AGO
   ---------------- ----------------
   04.05.2022 14:37 04.05.2022 14:07

   SQL>

   SQL> select sysdate, current_timestamp from dual;

    SYSDATE             CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
   ------------------- -------------------------------
   05.05.2022 07:48:19 05.05.22 07:48:19,200858 +02:00

   SQL>

   where submitted_datetime >= sysdate - interval '30' minute
```

Comment: Is that the code ?? Its a query, some prompts and a where clause - NOT an actual query. if that is your code of course it will fail. 
What is the data type of the column "SUBMITTED_DATETIME" ?

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't copy/paste my SQL*Plus session (from your previous question) into Apex (including the SQL> prompt) and expect it to work.

Code that *might* work is

```
select SCRAP_DATE,
       PAINT_SHOP,
       MODEL,
       COLOR,
       SCRAP_OWNER,
       DEPARTMENT_CODE,
       REASON_FOR_SCRAP,
       SCRAP_TYPE,
       BODY_TYPE,
       DETAILS,
       COMMENTS,
       SUBMITTED_DATETIME
from SCRAP_BODY_SYSTEM
where submitted_datetime >= sysdate - interval '30' minute;
```